# Python import class from module says module not found error

Tags: python, python-import

I am very confused at this very small point.

I have a `constants.py` file as below

```
if env=="qa":
    from myproject.qa import settings
else:
    from myproject.prod import settings
```

When I try to import it in another file as below I'm getting `module not found`

```
from constants import settings
from settings import *
```

But the below statements work

```
from constants import settings
print(settings.UserSettings)
```

Below is my directory structure

```
constants.py
myproject
 -qa
   -settings.py
 -prod
   -settings.py
```

Comment: So like we said the last time you asked this question a few minutes ago... we need to see your directory structure and what the settings file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the two versions.

**First version**

In the first version, you import `settings` as a module in `constants`.

Then, you try to import it again in another module (you didn't mention the name of it).

Then, you try to use the problematic statement: `from settings import *`.

**I guess that python just doesn't search for modules imported already when trying to use the `from` statement**. Unfortunately, I don't know if that's the actual reason why it's not working (I'm not an expert at that level).

**Second version**

In the second version, you import `settings` as a module in `constants`. Then, you try to import it again in another module (you didn't mention the name of it), and use an Object defined in it.

This works since python only tries to access an object of the imported module, and not "import" it again using the `from` statement.

**Possible solution**

You can change the import statement in `constants.py` to be:

```py
from myproject.settings import *
print(UserSettings) # works
```

I also think that the second option is not that bad:

```py
from constants import settings
print(settings.UserSettings) # works as well
```